# Problema ao fazer busca (FirstOrDefault) - Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Estou com um problema ao realizar a seguinte busca:

```
var estDel = bdprincipalEntities.unidades
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.uni_codigo == uni_codigo && x.Emp_codigo == Emp_codigo);
```

o campo é do tipo string:

```
public string uni_codigo { get; set; }
```

Meu problema é o seguinte: quando eu faço uma busca por um campo que recebe valor `"20"`, ou que comece com qualquer valor numérico, a busca de retorna null, mas se faço busca com `"metro"` da certo, não entendo oque pode ser, sendo que `"20"` é considerado string também

Registro existe no banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando você diz "que comece com qualquer valor numérico" você quer fazer algo como se fosse o "like" do SQL? Pois no seu select vai retornar apenas valores em que batam exatamente os valores que especificou tanto para uni_codigo quanto para Emp_codigo.

Comment: Essa seria a minha pergunta, você quer uma busca exata ou que **contenha** o valor?

Comment: Desculpa a demora, mas eu quero que retorne uma busca exata, o código tem que ser exatamente 20

Comment: O registro existe no banco de dados, vou postar uma imagem

Comment: O Emp_codigo no banco está nulo, por curiosidade, qual o valor que você está passando no seu Emp_codigo?

Comment: Ah, tem razão, não me toquei disso, eu passo valor padrão que é 1, esse é o erro, poste uma resposta que eu aceito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme explicado nos comentários da pergunta, o problema não está no `LINQ` e sim na busca efetuada, pois na linha do seu banco, conforme a imagem, a coluna "`Emp_codigo`" está nulo, mas está sendo passado um valor a mesma.

Desta forma, utilize o operador `OR` para esta consulta, nule o valor ou omita o campo de sua busca, dependendo da sua regra de negócio.